# Create dynamic categories depending on values

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to automatically sort my values and place them into some defined categories.

Here is an explanation of what I mean:

This basic loop goes through my custom post type `archiv` and returns all values of the custom field `year`:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'archiv' );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
      the_field('year');
    endwhile;
?>
```

`the_field('year')` would return e.g. `2016`, `2001`, `1995`, `1941` etc.

Those values should automatically be placed into some defined categories. The categories which I would like to display have always the interval of 10 years except the first category.

**Example of the categories**

- Today - 2010
- 2010 - 2000
- 2000 - 1990
- 1990 - 1980
- ...

**Example of the result**

- Today - 2010

  - 2016
- 2010 - 2000

  - 2001
- 2000 - 1990

  - 1995
- 1990 - 1980
- ...

Since I do not know where to start, I would be very glad if someone could give me an idea how I could create all those dynamic categories and how to insert the values into them. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how to do this. This is an example of how it could work:

```
$date_up =  ceil(date('Y') / 10) * 10;
$date_down =    ceil(date('Y') / 10) * 10 - 10;
echo 'The current date is between ' . $date_up .' and '. $date_down;
```